# How do I make this work? I need my variable options to be more specific

Tags: jquery

Can someone tell me what the best way is to make this work in a way that says "This EXACT variable"?  Currently, it executes the code if it matches part of it.  For example, if the page title is 'Americas' and 'Americas Fleet' it equals true.  I just want it to be true if it's an exact match.

```
    var options = ['Americas Fleet','Americas'];

    /* EVENTS */
    $.each(options, function() {

        var that = this.toString(),
        present = $('#pageTitle span:contains(' + that + ')');

        if (present.length) {
        $('a.events-link').attr('href', that + '-Events.aspx');
        return;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `:contains()` selector, you can try `.filter()`.

```
var that = this.toString(),
    present = $('#pageTitle span').filter(function(){
        // trim the value just in case there is any whitespace
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === that;
    });
```